# How to change my list data according to selected date?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-fragments

Within a fragment I call diaryViewModel with parameter a date inside onActivityCreated():

```
        mDiaryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(this.getActivity().getApplication(), date)).get(DiaryViewModel.class);
```

Also, I have a textview with the current date on the top of the layout(fragment) which is between two arrows. The left arrow indicates that when it is clicked the current date will change to minus one day and plus one day for the other arrow. Based on the changed date I want the live data(recycler view) to change as well. Here's the code that is called onActivityCreated() and I inserted the same inside the onClick method of the arrows.

```
  mDiaryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(this.getActivity().getApplication(), date)).get(DiaryViewModel.class);

    mDiaryViewModel.getTodayEntries(date).observe(this, new Observer<List<Diary>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Diary> diary) {
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            adapter.setDiary(diary);
        }
    });
```

Adapter code:

```
public class DiaryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DiaryListAdapter.DiaryViewHolder> {

class DiaryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView timeItemView;
    private final TextView foodNameItemView;
    private final TextView gramsItemView;

    private DiaryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        timeItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        foodNameItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.f_name);
        gramsItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.f_grams);

    }
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Diary> mDiary; // Cached copy of user

DiaryListAdapter(Context context) { mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); }


@Override
public DiaryListAdapter.DiaryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_diary, parent, false);
    return new DiaryListAdapter.DiaryViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DiaryListAdapter.DiaryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (mDiary != null) {
        Diary current = mDiary.get(position);
        holder.timeItemView.setText(String.valueOf(current.getTime()));
        holder.foodNameItemView.setText(current.getFoodName());
        holder.gramsItemView.setText(String.valueOf(current.getGrams()));
    } else {
        // Covers the case of data not being ready yet.
        holder.foodNameItemView.setText("No User");
    }
}

void setDiary(List<Diary> diaries){
    mDiary = diaries;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// getItemCount() is called many times, and when it is first called,
// mWords has not been updated (means initially, it's null, and we can't return null).
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mDiary != null)
        return mDiary.size();
    else return 0;
}
```

}

Here's the prototype of the screen to help you more:
[prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeBPw.png)

Answer (score 0):

After updating the data, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method. this will update the data

```
mDiaryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(this.getActivity().getApplication(), date)).get(DiaryViewModel.class);

mDiaryViewModel.getTodayEntries(date).observe(this, new Observer<List<Diary>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Diary> diary) {
        // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
        adapter.setDiary(diary);
        // This will refresh the data 
        **adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()**
    }
});
```

Let me know if refreshing the data is not an issue

Comment: Still data are not changing on click.

Comment: are you sure that data is received in the ibserver?

Comment: Please put a log in onchaged method and see if its reaching that point or not

Comment: Yes, It is reaching it.

Comment: can you post your adapter code, it'll be easy to debug

Comment: Everything looks good. I don't see any issue in the code posted. Please print the dairy object in onChanged method. I'm not sure if its really getting new data or not. If its gets old data, it means "date" value is new date value is not being passed to the observable.